# Attachments in Email

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

I am developing an app which requires to send email to a person. Everything works fine except the attachment. And here is the piece of code for that

```
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(  "file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+""+attach));
```

attach is the file i got by browsing in the phone.
But the attachment is not being sent Please Help.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my blogpost found [here](http://androtrash.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-write-mail-with-attachment-on.html):

> Creating a mail on Android which the user may send with the app of his
>   choice is widely spread on the net. But it isn't how you attach a file
>   which will be send by googlemail.
>
> The problem here is that the gmail app only want to send files which
>   are located on the sdcard
>
> ```
> Intent mail = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
> mail.setType("application/octet-stream");
> mail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"my@mail.com"});
> mail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
> mail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message");
> mail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/file.txt"));
> PrefAct.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mail, "Send mail via..."));
> ```
>
> As said gmail will refuse your attachment when the user sends the mail
>   when the file isn't located on the ExternalStorage.

Comment: Thanx a lot!! that was spot on :)